# Angular view: always going back to otherwise link (updated code)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I have a problem...

```
.state('tabs', {
    url: '/tabs',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})

.state('tabs.personal', {
url: '/personal',
    views: {
        'personalGoals-view': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/personalGoals.html',
          controller: 'personalCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.personal.personalview', {
url: 'tabs/personal/personalview',
    views: {
        'personalview-view': {
          template: 'hello',
          controller: 'personalViewCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

and this is my link:

```
    <ion-view view-title="PersonalGoals">
        <ion-content class="has-footer">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="goal in goals" href="#" ui-sref="tabs.personal.personalview">
                <span class="goal-lists">{{goal.goaltitle}}</span>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

(pound sign)/tabs/personal/personalview doesn't show and goes back to my otherwise link... I don't know why... please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ui-sref`:

```
<ion-view view-title="PersonalGoals">
    <ion-content class="has-footer">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="goal in goals" ui-sref="tabs.personal.personalview">
            <span class="goal-lists">{{goal.goaltitle}}</span>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things :

When using ui-router use ui-sref="tabs.personal.personalview" it's way better than href.

2nd Your state is a grand children of the state tabs and URL are relative to their parent states. So his full URL would be

```
<tabs URL>/<tabs.personal URL>/tabs/personal/personalview
```

If i guessed correctly how you did declare your states this will give something like

```
tabs/tabs/personal/tabs/personal/personalview
```

If you click on a link using ui-sref.

Comment: I'm a bit lost at "tabs/tabs/personal/tabs/personal/personalview " and also how/where will I apply the "<tabs URL>/<tabs.personal URL>/tabs/personal/personalview" ?

Comment: Just replace your href in your <a> tag by  ui-sref="tabs.personal.personalview" and check the URL ;) If this does not work add href="#" along with the ui-sref.

Comment: I changed "url: 'tabs/personal/personalview'," to "url: '/personalview'," still not working...

Comment: Try using **ui-sref="tabs.personal.personalview" instead of href**

Comment: If the URL changed that means it's worked, it's your configuration of state that is not good. Add the definition of the states tabs and tabs.personal with their template in your post to dig further please.

Comment: I added more code from the app.js... the personalGoals.html's contents are just those 7 lines...

Comment: So for the personalview state change the URL to /personalview. Don't use views in state when you have only one. Use directly templteUrl and controller at the same level than **url**. And check that you have the tag ui-view in the state tabs and tabs.personal